# Error : Ajax call to server inside jquery function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I am trying to make an ajax call to a server in my local network installed with LAMP who is running wordpress. I am currently doing changes to files in a wordpress plugin.

I want to call a php file located into my server to get json data to build a chart from a sql request.

So I have ajaxStatistics.php where I coded the sql request and the json encode.

Now I am in statistics.js where I have my function to build a chart and this is where I do the ajax call :

```
jQuery(function() { 
    /**
     * call the ajaxStats.php file to fetch the result from db table.
     */
    $.ajax({
        url : "192.168.1.100/wp-content/plugins/pluginname/ajaxStatistics.php",
        type : "GET",
        success : function(data){
            console.log(data);
            ...
```

The result is an Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'ajax' of undefined

```
at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (statistics.js:92)
    at i (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:2)
    at Function.ready (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:2)
    at HTMLDocument.K (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:2)
```

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: Please show us error output also

Comment: I edited with error message

Comment: Have you included jQuery?

Comment: try to replace $ with jQuey => jQuery.ajax ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to access $ as jQuery before it gets initialized so to make it in proper way, you can use DOM load event of it like so...

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    function build_statistics() {
        $.ajax({
        url : "http://192.168.1.100/wp-content/plugins/pluginname/ajaxStatistics.php",
        type : "GET",
        success : function(data){
            console.log(data);
        }
    }
});
```

And then call it like

```
build_statistics()
```

Comment: It says net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED now

Comment: I solved it by using : http:/wp-content/plugins/pluginname/ajaxStatistics.php instead of Ipadress/etc/... Anyway, thanks for your help guys !

Answer (score 0):

That means that jquery has not been loaded.

Make sure that you have the script in your html, and also wrap the call to this function sendData inside a

```
$(document).ready(function(){
//do stuff
})
```

Comment: I have the script linked in my html page.I wraped with document.ready, it changed the error to : Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function.

Comment: is jquery.min.js included before script or after ?
make sure linked script is after jQuery.min.js

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your `$` variable is unreachable in your code.

Try this:

```
jQuery(function() { 
    /**
     * call the ajaxStats.php file to fetch the result from db table.
     */
    var $ = jQuery;

    $.ajax({
        url : "http://192.168.1.100/wp-content/plugins/pluginname/ajaxStatistics.php",
        type : "GET",
        success : function(data){
            console.log(data);
            ...
```

And also make sure to add a `http` or `https` in your url.

Comment: Thanks I think it worked since I got the error : GET http://192.168.1.100/192.168.1.100/wp-content/plugins/pluginname/ajaxStatistics.php 404 (Not Found), the problem now is the access of the file, right? It s strange that it show the Ip adress two times tho...

Comment: I changed with https, I have the error : connection refused, Do I have to change something on the server ?

Comment: can you show your current code somewhere, because from the above url i can see, that you inserted the IP twice.